# Dependency Injection of a service usage inside the global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I'm using Ninject to do dependency injection. I have a userService in which I need to access from the global.asax file.

How do I dependency inject this?

```
    private IUserService userService;//<--this
    protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            var identity = new CustomIdentity(authTicket);
            string[] userRoles = userService.GetRolesForUser(identity.Name);// <-- Used here.
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, userRoles);
            Context.User = principal;
        }
    }
```

I did my bindings in another file(`NinjectMVC3`) using the `WebActivator`. Which was created by the nuget package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of injection try to resolve in your method...

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var userService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserService>();
  ...
}
```

Don't forget to set dependency resolver to Ninject's implementation before use, for example in your NinjectMVC3 (WebActivator) file.

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver( ... ));
```

Comment: nevermind. What happened was that it needs the ninject kernel (which is of type IRootResolver). So I moved the SetResolver code to the `NinjectMVC3` `CreateKernel` method.